# Wp-admin Custom User Management

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, users

I am working on a plugin for which I will have to develop a backend page similar to the built-in "Users" one, in the sense that it will be basically do the same things: list the existing users ( using the `WP_List_Table` class ), edit / remove, and add new ones as well. The only difference is that it will have a couple of additional fields, as well as some other custom functionality.

My question is: should I be working with the already existing WP functions for handling users: `wp_insert_user`, `wp_update_user`, `wp_remove_user` or is it recommended to make direct calls to the database? Although this may be a little more complicated, I was wondering if it's the way recommended / only way to go.

Comment: Always use the existing functions, if those functions do what you need.

Comment: Well that's what I was initially thinking about doing in order to save time, but I was wondering if it's the right Wordpress-way of doing things, are there any guidelines available on this? It's the first major plugin I'm developing, so I apologize if my question is a stupid one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use the existing functions, if those functions do what you need. That way, your code has the best chance of staying functional as the Core changes. If you make direct queries to the database then you have to keep track of changes to the database and alter your code accordingly.

Using Core functions also means that hooks have the best chance of working where they are intended to work. If you make direct queries to the database you bypass those hooks, unless you make a special effort to support them. Again, you will have to monitor changes and update your code accordingly.

Also, the database is complicated making some queries are extremely complicated and easy to get wrong. Let the Core handle it when it can.

I am not against making direct queries the database but it is not something that should be done lightly. If this is a first plugin, avoid it if all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I never even considered some of the points you brought up.